# Method that takes a delegate as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, delegates

I'm trying to create a method that takes a delegate as one of its parameters but its not working. What am I doing wrong? I'm getting the error "callback is a variable but is used like a method" on the line that has `windowAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(callback)`.

```
private void animateWindowWidth(Window window, double width, double duration, Delegate callback)
{
    window.BeginInit();
    window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        DoubleAnimation windowAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        windowAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
        windowAnimation.From = window.Width;
        windowAnimation.To = width;
        windowAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
        windowAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(callback);
        window.BeginAnimation(Window.WidthProperty, windowAnimation);
    }), null);
    window.EndInit();
}
```

Comment: Let me suggest a bit more elegant (imo) syntax: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { });`

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference? Is it just a shortcut to the same thing?

Comment: No difference, as far as I know, just a matter of taste, as I highlighted from the beginning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just thought I'd explain a bit of why `Delegate` by itself does not work.

`Delegate` is not a true delegate, but a representation of one. It's basically a variable that holds a delegate. This is why an error is given for treating a variable like a method.

A simple example (granted you'd probably never do this) is if you have two delegates to do addition. One with ints and the other with floats. You can store the delegates in a `Delegate` object and pass that to another function that calls `DynamicInvoke()` on one variable:

```
    void MyMethod(Delegate d)
    {
        d.DynamicInvoke(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
    }
```

No matter which of the two delegates are stored in the `Delegate` object, you get the appropriate functionality.

In your case, `windowAnimation.Completed` is expecting an actual delegate method, such as EventHandler. In addition, the constructor of EventHandler expects a delegate method. So using a `Delegate` object in either situation will not work.

You'll have to wrap it in a delegate or use a lambda function to place the true method call

```
windowAnimation.Completed += (s,e) => callback.DynamicInvoke();
```

or changed `callback` to an `EventHandler` and create a new one when you when you want to call this method.

Comment: Thanks! This covered everything I wanted to know and I now understand the reasoning behind why my approach wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your method signature to:

```
private void animateWindowWidth(
    Window window, 
    double width, 
    double duration, 
    EventHandler callback)
```

and that line that causes the error to

```
windowAnimation.Completed += callback;
```

Then create a new `EvenHandler` when you call the method.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is it not possible to do it the way I was?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Action` instead of `Delegate` and replace this string:

```cs
windowAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(callback);
```

with this:

```cs
windowAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => callback();
```

So, in the end it should look like this:

```cs
private void animateWindowWidth(Window window, double width, double duration, Action callback)
{
    window.BeginInit();
    window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        DoubleAnimation windowAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        windowAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration));
        windowAnimation.From = window.Width;
        windowAnimation.To = width;
        windowAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
        windowAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => callback());
        window.BeginAnimation(Window.WidthProperty, windowAnimation);
    }), null);
    window.EndInit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me. I get "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" as an error.

Comment: Sergey V. did you compile it? At least you should write `windowAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => callback.DynamicInvoke(s, e);`. But why would one ever do so to add a simple event handler?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't compile it ). To get it working, just replace Delegate with Action.

Comment: It's working now that I changed it to an action. Do you know why it is I can't use a delegate and need to use an action like you showed?